# EditPart with visible figure not in EditPartRegistry - why?

Tags: java, eclipse-gef

In one of the `EditPart`s in my GEF editor - specifically in my override of `refreshVisuals()` - I'm trying to loop through all `EditPart`s. I'm doing this with

```
for (Object part : getViewer().getEditPartRegistry().values()) {
...
}
```

For most cases this works fine. However, I've found a few `EditPart`s with visible figures in the editor which aren't present in the `EditPartRegistry`.

How can this be? An `EditPart` with a visible figure (I can interact with via it's `EditPart`!) should surely be present in the `EditPartRegistry`?

Answer (score 1):

EditPart registry is mapping model objects to editparts. This is not quite the same as figures -> editpoarts map the viasual registry.
Perhaps there is an editpart without the model somewhere? Or same model object for 2 different editparts?
In addition check if any of your editparts override (add/removeNotify) or register/unregister methods